# Square is not showing a specific item in catalog

Tags: square-connect

This is the first time that I see this issue. So far we have added the items to the catalog and we can see it on the API, but yesterday we've added a new item (just like the others)  and the item is not visible on the catalog throught the API.

Is there something new or something has changed on the API to pull the catalog items?. The item has the same config as the others.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a copy of the request and response you got when making the item that we can dig into? is it possible you used a different access token?

Comment: Hi @tristansokol 

Right now we call the list catalog with the following line:
$results = $api_instance->listCatalog($cursor, $types);

And the results we get are all the catalog items that we later use to filter.

Right now we are using two different access token, one for Canada and one for United States. With the US access token we don't have any issues, we can pull all items we add, but with the CA access token we are not able to get the new added item, we only get the old ones and that's the issue so far. There is only one new item added for Canada and we're not able to see it.

Comment: Hi Julio, would you mind emailing me your application id (client_id) so we can look further into this?

Comment: Hi @BryanW. I already send you an email with the information. Thanks!